# Watch OS 2: Is it possible to get bluetooth signal strength of connectivity between paired iPhone and Apple Watch?

Tags: swift, core-bluetooth, watchos-2

The title is self-explanatory. I have tried CoreBluetooth but I don't see Apple Watch as a connected peripheral.

Comment: Why do you need the signal strength?

Comment: @Michał Ciuba: To tell, how far they are from each other

Comment: I don't know if it's available on watchOS, or if it would get you what you want, but you might want to look at the [Multipeer Connectivity Framework](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/MultipeerConnectivity/Reference/MultipeerConnectivityFramework/).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible.

Use `retrieveConnectedPeripherals(withServices serviceUUIDs: [CBUUID]) -> [CBPeripheral]`. You need to specify the a bluetooth GATT characteristic for the serviceUUID. I used the [Continuity](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204681) UUID: "`D0611E78-BBB4-4591-A5F8-487910AE4366`". The function returns a CBPeripheral object which you can then use `connect(_ peripheral: CBPeripheral, options: [String : Any]? = nil)` to connect to.

After you confirmed that your iOS app is connected to the watch with `centralManager(_ central: CBCentralManager, didConnect peripheral: CBPeripheral`, you can then use `readRSSI()` to find the signal strength between the iPhone and the Apple Watch.

Answer (score 0):

You need to check the [RSSI](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/CoreBluetooth/Reference/CBPeripheral_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/CBPeripheral/readRSSI) signal level.

You can use:

```
- (void)centralManager:(CBCentralManager *)central didDiscoverPeripheral:(CBPeripheral *)peripheral advertisementData:(NSDictionary *)advertisementData RSSI:(NSNumber *)RSSI {
    NSLog(@"Did discover peripheral. peripheral: %@ rssi: %@, UUID: %@ advertisementData: %@ ", peripheral, RSSI, peripheral.UUID, advertisementData);
    //Do something when a peripheral is discovered.

    rssiLabel.text = [RSSI stringValue];

    [manager retrievePeripherals:[NSArray arrayWithObject:(id)peripheral.UUID]];}
```

[image]